# JQコマンドでJSONの特定の値を抽出したい

Tags: json, jq

JQコマンドでのJSONの加工をして、特定の値のみ抽出したいのですが、
マニュアルやサイトを見て、いろいろ試行錯誤したのですが、
どうしたらよいかわかりません。
どなたか、助けていただけないでしょうか？

詳細は、下記のようになります。

## 元データ

```js
[
  {
    "room_id": 99999999,
    "name": "佐藤一郎",
    "type": "direct",
    "role": "member",
    "sticky": true,
    "unread_num": 2,
    "mention_num": 1,
    "mytask_num": 0,
    "message_num": 28,
    "file_num": 3,
    "task_num": 0,
    "icon_path": "https://appdata.chatwork.com/avatar/99999999/99999999.png",
    "last_update_time": 1556586317
  },
 {
    "room_id": 88888888,
    "name": "山田 花子",
    "type": "direct",
    "role": "member",
    "sticky": false,
    "unread_num": 0,
    "mention_num": 0,
    "mytask_num": 0,
    "message_num": 1,
    "file_num": 0,
    "task_num": 0,
    "icon_path": "https://appdata.chatwork.com/avatar/88888888/88888888.rsz.jpg",
    "last_update_time": 88888888
  }
]
```

## 得たい結果

```
999999999
88888888
```

## 試したコマンドと実行結果

`$ curl -X GET -H "X-ChatWorkToken: XXXXXXXX" "https://api.chatwork.com/v2/rooms/" | jq  'room_id'`

```
jq: error: room_id/0 is not defined at <top-level>, line 1:
room_id
jq: 1 compile error
curl: (23) Failed writing body (0 != 16384)
```

`$ curl -X GET -H "X-ChatWorkToken: XXXXXXXX" "https://api.chatwork.com/v2/rooms/" | jq  '.room_id'`

```
jq: error (at <stdin>:0): Cannot index array with string "room_id"
```

`$ curl -X GET -H "X-ChatWorkToken: XXXXXXXX" "https://api.chatwork.com/v2/rooms/" | jq  '[room_id]'`

```
jq: error: room_id/0 is not defined at <top-level>, line 1:
[room_id] 
jq: 1 compile error
curl: (23) Failed writing body (0 != 16384)
```

`$ curl -X GET -H "X-ChatWorkToken: XXXXXXXX" "https://api.chatwork.com/v2/rooms/" | jq  '[.room_id]'`

```
jq: error (at <stdin>:0): Cannot index array with string "room_id"
```

`$ curl -X GET -H "X-ChatWorkToken: XXXXXXXX" "https://api.chatwork.com/v2/rooms/" | jq  '[{room_id}]'`

```
jq: error (at <stdin>:0): Cannot index array with string "room_id"
```

`$ curl -X GET -H "X-ChatWorkToken: XXXXXXXX" "https://api.chatwork.com/v2/rooms/" | jq  '[{.room_id}]'`

```
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected FIELD (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
[{.room_id}]  
jq: 1 compile error
curl: (23) Failed writing body (0 != 16384)
```

Comment: `.[]` を使って配列の中身を取り出すとよろしいかと。`jq '.[]|.room_id'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

配列へのアクセスとして `.[]` を使うことで取得できます。

`$ curl -X GET -H "X-ChatWorkToken: XXXXXXXX" "https://api.chatwork.com/v2/rooms/" | jq '.[].room_id'`

```
99999999
88888888
```

Comment: できました！
誠にありがとうございます！！